# Ubuntu 20.04 not recognizing Archer T3U Plus

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, usb, tp-link

I'm having issues with recognizing my external Wifi adapter. I used the exact same model of adapter(Archer T3U Plus, AC1300) before and installed the aircrack drivers as directed in [this answered question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233440/tplink-archer-t2u-ubuntu-20-04). After installing the drivers and using the `sudo modprobe 88XXau` command, the green LED lit up and I was able to connect to networks and browse with zero issues. However after losing said device, I replaced it with an identical model. As the drivers had already been installed, I expected it to work out of the box. But it didn't. I tried using the  modprobe command again and it didn't work. I then used `sudo dkms remove 8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025 --all` to remove the aircrack drivers and install them again to no avail. I've tried rebooting several times, running modprobe again and still nothing.

`lsusb` shows this:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b3aa Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0489:e062 Foxconn / Hon Hai
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03eb:8813 Atmel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2357:0138 TP-Link 802.11ac NIC
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0458:0186 KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) Genius DX-120 Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The device also works perfectly in Windows so it's probably not a hardware issue.

Any input is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your new device isn’t an rtl88XXau, but a rtl8822bu. Fortunately, [this answer from last year](https://askubuntu.com/a/1256330/1222991) will get you running quickly 

Comment: Thanks buddy, worked perfect,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try :**

```
git clone https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver.git
cd RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver/
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

**After each kernel update, you must recompile:**

```
cd ~/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver/
make clean
git pull
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, worked perfect,

Comment: No Problem, Im Glad I Could Help, Support Me At My Youtube Channel : https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoROPepARvT7Tp4qX2vOyVg